# TSQL: How do I move data between SQLServer instances?

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have two SQLSever instances, each of them have an identical schema. One is running in SQLAzure, the other is a standared SQLServer 2008 instance. I need to copy the data from the Azure database to my local instance.

Essentially I want to do this:

```
insert LOCAL_TABLE (col1, col2)
select col1, col2
from AZURE_TABLE
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to move data between SQL Servers, and if one of them is SQL Azure you have couple of options:

1. [SQL Azure Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh456371.aspx)
2. [Using SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benko/archive/2009/08/19/using-sql-management-studio-2008-with-sql-data-services-sql-in-the-cloud.aspx)
3. Write your own code that will move data using, most probably [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.
4. If you would like to just copy all the data, you could also use [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) - you can omit the option for coping the schema, and let it just copy the data.

**EDIT**

And as, by the original answer from Matthew PK, you could link **to** your SQL Azure server **from** your on-prem Server, but this is only an option when you just want to do some ad-hoc testing. I would not use this approach in production for constantly syncing data.

Comment: +1 If it's going to be a regular running script, rather than ad-hoc or dev, then I think SSIS is the way to go.

Comment: We ended up using a linked server, so I could run a simple insert statement. This was for a one time data migration, and not for any kind of regular synchronization. Worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish that in a single statements using linked servers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.100).aspx

**EDIT:** Here is a link which appears to explain how to link to SQL Azure: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/08/linked-servers-to-sql-azure.aspx

**EDIT:** Here is a write-up on connecting to Azure with SSMS 
http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2009/11/11/Connecting-to-SQL-Azure-with-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008-R2.aspx

Otherwise I believe you need to do it in two statements.

Comment: Linked Servers feature is not supported in SQL Azure! And, context switching is also not supported in SQL Azure.

Comment: @astaykov I added a link which seems to explain how to do it, though I have never done it myself.

Comment: Your link shows very outdated information, plus it just shows how to connect to SQL Azure from SSMS, and nothing more. Which does not answers @mtmurdock question.

Comment: @astaykov my link is dated March-2011, it certainly appears to answer the question. The example code is querying from Azure and inserting into a local table...

Comment: that one came after the one the one from Nov. 2009

Comment: SQL Azure does not support ***creating*** Linked Servers (as in, creating a link to another server).  That is not the same as creating a Linked Server definition in another SQL Server ***to*** a SQL Azure database.  AFAIK, that works fine.

Comment: @astaykov... One link explaining what linked servers are, another explaining how to link to sql azure and another explaining how to get it into SSMS. Each is relevant, and using the method in the 2nd link is precisely what the question asks.

Comment: agree! you got the vote on the previous comment, let's not covert this into chat:)

Comment: @astaykov not trying to chat, trying to explain why my answer is valid because somebody voted it down.

Answer (score 0):

Linked Server is not officially supported. However, Here are couple of resources that are supported and would help you do what you are looking for:

1) Check out SQL Azure Dac Examples: http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/

2) The other options is SQL Azure Data SYNC.

Comment: SQL Azure Data Sync seems like the logical choice, especially for continued updates/syncs.

Comment: Yes! Thanks mcollier for adding that info.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to go, but we are not trying to synchronize the two databases. I just needed the data in one table this one time. Thanks though, I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use a product like ["SQL Data Compare"](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) from redgate. I am not a Azure user, but I am guessing it would work, I have used it for a few years and its pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time copy or ongoing?
If one-time, then use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard (from Codeplex)
If ongoing then use SQL Azure data sync

Also you can verify that the schema is compliant with SQL Server Data Tools in VS, just set the target to SQL Azure or to SQL Server 2012, or 2008 and then build and any/all schema errors will show up.